# Tryton web client version mismatch?

Tags: python, version, webclient, tryton

I am using GNU Health and I have installed trytond server 6.0.24 and tryton desktop 6.0.10 and when I install trytond web client it was installed successfully but when I open it on localhost it shows the error Version Mismatch.
How can I match the version of the tryton web client with the trytond server?

[This is the error shown on the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jjH9.jpg)

I have tried to find to version of tryton web client but it never works.

Answer (score 1):

The error is right, you installed the wrong version of the web client. You should install the 6.0 series of [tryton-sao](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tryton-sao/v/6.0.27). Sao is the name of web client is not the same as the desktop client. For example, you can install the [6.0.27](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tryton-sao/v/6.0.27) version (which is the latest at time of writing) which should work for your setup. Note that you should also remove the current installed version to avoid conflicts.

This is because tryton requires all clients (web and desktop) to run the same series (two first digits of version) as the server you are connecting to.

Comment: i need to remove trytond server installed version or just tryton sao version that is installed? and how can i remove it?

Comment: You just need to remove the sao version and replace it with the newer one.